# How to get user location updates in background on Android 8.0?

Tags: android, location

In my app I want to get user location updates every 10 minutes,but as the documentation says

> If your app receives location updates from a background service, it receives less frequent updates on Android 8.0 (API level 26) compared to older versions of Android. Specifically, a background service cannot receive location updates more than a few times per hour.

So what will be the best practice to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In Oreo location updates limits only for background services, according to documentation:

> If an app is in the foreground on a device running Android 8.0 (API
>   level 26), the location update behavior is the same as on Android
>   7.1.1 (API level 25) and lower.

So you can run your service in foreground, following link will help you to understand foreground service:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground